# NHibernate: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: nhibernate

I'm currently struggling with this "**Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute**" issue.

I have searched about this error message, and it's all related to the foreach statement. I do have the some foreach statements, but they are just simply representing the data. I did not using any **remove** or **add** inside the foreach statement.

NOTE:

1. The error randomly happens (about 4-5 times a day).
2. The application is the MVC website.
3. There are about 5 users operate this applications (about 150 orders a day). Could it be some another users modified the collection, and then occur this error?
4. I have log4net setup and the settings can be found [here](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/Configuringlog4netforusewithNHibernate)
5. *Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor*  I do have parameterless public constructor in AdminProductController

Does anyone know why this happen and how to resolve this issue?

A friend (Oskar) mentioned that

> "Theory: Maybe the problem is that
>   your configuration and session factory
>   is initialized on the first request
>   after application restart. If a second
>   request comes in before the first
>   request is finished, maybe it will
>   also try to initialize and then
>   triggering this problem somehow."

Many thanks.

Daoming

**Here is the error message:**

**System.InvalidOperationException
Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
System.InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'WebController.Controllers.Admin.AdminProductController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> NHibernate.MappingException: Could not configure datastore from input stream DomainModel.Entities.Mappings.OrderProductVariant.hbm.xml ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.**
   at System.Collections.ArrayList.ArrayListEnumeratorSimple.MoveNext()
   at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaSet.AddSchemaToSet(XmlSchema schema)
   at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaSet.Add(String targetNamespace, XmlSchema schema)
   at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaSet.Add(XmlSchema schema)
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.LoadMappingDocument(XmlReader hbmReader, String name)
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddInputStream(Stream xmlInputStream, String name)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.LogAndThrow(Exception exception)
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddInputStream(Stream xmlInputStream, String name)
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddResource(String path, Assembly assembly)
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddAssembly(Assembly assembly)
   at DomainModel.RepositoryBase..ctor()
   at WebController.Controllers._baseController..ctor()
   at WebController.Controllers.Admin.AdminProductController..ctor()
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean fillCache)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oskar is right. Two separate threads are trying to initialize the session factory at the same time. Suggest you put some locking around the initialization code, perhaps just using the `lock` keyword and a suitable synchronization object. We've used a pattern like this, using one of the locks from the Wintellect PowerThreading library:

```
using (_lock.WaitToRead())
{
    if (Factory != null) return Factory;
}
using (_lock.WaitToWrite())
{
    if (Factory != null) return Factory;
    Factory = ConfigureFactory();
    return Factory;
}
```

You could more simply just use the `lock` keyword and a double-check locking pattern like so:

```
class NestedSessionManager
{
    internal static SessionManager _sessionManager;
    private static readonly object _syncRoot = new object();

    internal static SessionManager sessionManager
    {
        get
        {
            if (_sessionManager != null) return _sessionManager;
            lock (_syncRoot)
            {
                if (_sessionManager != null) return _sessionManager;
                _sessionManager = new SessionManager();
                return _sessionManager;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: HI David, I have added the code sample. I guess I'm building configuration multiple times from the log4net details. Could you advise me? Thank you.

Comment: What about the constructor in the controller - can you post that?

Comment: HI David, the controller sample code has been included.  Many thanks.

Comment: Hi David, How could I implement the lock into the existing code? Could you please provide a sample for me?

Comment: Thank you very much. David. I know how to use the lock keyword now. :)